# Is there any chance to find drivers for my Wireless Adapter?

Tags: drivers

So I've been suffering the connection/disconnection of my wireless signal for some time, in different OS (arch and ubuntu). Suddenly it disconnects and informs "wlp1s0 no carrier" or something very close to this.

I suppose this may have to do with the drivers. I'm looking the ones for this card:

```
RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

But I can't find it anywhere. Any help?

Comment: yes, there is a chance .. good luck in your search ... have you considered the possibility that the hardware may be failing?

Comment: @jsotola no i havent

Comment: IIRC both the firmware and kernel driver for the RTL88xx have a reputation to be buggy. Make sure both are the newest version, with a bit of luck your problem has already been fixed. If not, file a bug report (the more upstream, the better).

Comment: Alright. How do I make sure this things are in newest version? @dirkt

Comment: Current kernel release is [here](https://www.kernel.org/). `cat /proc/version` will give the release of your running kernel. Update from your distro as needed (will be a bit behind), if that is not sufficient, download kernel release and compile yourself (google). If you can't do that, wait until your distro picks it up.

Comment: I'm using the stable kernel. and my laptop is not very new. 2017 or so.